# Xcode ld: library not found for -LFSCalendar

Tags: ios, xcode, fscalendar

I have an existing Xcode iOS project that uses `FSCalendar` library.
I have now opened this project on another mac computer with Xcode installed.

When I build my project, I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -LFSCalendar
```

In the Project --> Build Settings --> Search Paths I see:

**Library Search Paths:**

```
"build/Debug-iphoneos/FSCalendar"
"build/Release-iphoneos/FSCalendar"
```

**Question 1**
What do I have to do to get this to build? Do I have to copy the FSCalendar folder to the Debug and Release locations above etc?

**Question 2**
Should there be an actual library file somewhere called FSCalendar in my project directory? there is a folder called FSCalendar which contains all the FSCalendar source code files.  Do these files get built into a library output file??

Comment: And how do you integrate/install FSCalendar to your project?

Comment: Xcode versions are same in both systems ?

Comment: Currently there is a folder called FSCalendar in my project which has all the fscalendar code files and my code just uses e.g. #import fscalendar.h

Comment: Under my main project folder there is a folder called Pods which contains an FSCalendar folder.

Comment: yes they are both the same versions of xCode (9.3)

Comment: Please use this command 'pod install' in the terminal. Install the pods and make sure you are running project.workspace not project file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about this [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) - it will depend on how you've integrated with your project. The [projects readme](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/README.md) describes methods using [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) and manual integration.

#### Carthage

From [the doc's](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#running-a-project-that-uses-carthage)

> **Running a project that uses Carthage**
>
> After you’ve finished the above steps and pushed your changes, other users of the project only need to fetch the repository and run `carthage bootstrap` to get started with the frameworks you’ve added.

#### CocoaPods

In your projects root directory where your `Podfile` exists, it `Terminal.app` you should be able to run:

`$ pod install`

#### Manual Integration

If you've used the manual options then you probably already have a target for check the *Build Phases* tab of your projects main target. Then check the list of files under the head **Compile Sources** (you may need to click on the disclosure triangle to unfold the list).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you manually added `FSCalendar` in project,

```
Solution 1:
```

While adding to project you forget to tick `Copy item if needed`. Please add FSCaldendar folder again and tick Copy item if needed.

```
In case you added with cocoa pods, then try solution 2.

Solution 2:
```

If you added with cocoa pods, Please `go to terminal -> go to project directory -> and run command -> pod install`